# Add a Plotly Express trace to a Graph Objects go.Figure() with multiple traces?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly.graph-objects

I am trying to visualize timestamps from different pandas dataframes using plotly Graph Objects. After successfully adding traces as go.Scatter() plots, I would now like to add a px.timeline() plot as a trace. Is this generally possible?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go


df=pd.read_json(file1.json)
df2=pd.read_json(file2.json)
df3=pd.read_json(file3.json)

fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df.column1, y=df.column2, name='name1', mode='markers')
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df2.column1, y=df2.column2, name='name2', mode='markers')
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df3.column1, y=df3.column2, name='name3', mode='markers')
)
#### add px trace ###
fig.update_traces(marker_size=10)

fig.show()
```

This is working well so far.
Now, I would like to add the px.timeline() plot as a trace to my figure.
I tried:

```
fig.add_trace(
    px.timeline(df,x_start="column1",
                x_end="column2", y='column3')
```

This raises the Value Error:

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'data' property of [...]
```

Is there a workaround to adding px.-Plots to a go.Figure() ?

Comment: I can't say for sure since you don't present any data, but I think you need to replace the timeline data with a bar chart or something like that, and use a graph object to draw the graph.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try including **.data[0]**

```
fig.add_trace(
px.timeline(df,x_start="column1",
            x_end="column2", y='column3').data[0])
```